# Why did modifying the WebView Layout Parameter fix the 0 height body issue?

Tags: android, css, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin WebView that was not displaying my HTML correctly. It was set to fill the whole screen, however the body height in the HTML was still 0px.

I also had a div in the html styled:

```
position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
```

This was 0px high as well.

I tried these options:

```
  webView.SetInitialScale(1);
  webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
  webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
```

Which did not help, but I noticed that webView.LayoutParameters.Height was -2 for some reason.

I added this code, and suddenly my absolutely positioned div has height.

```
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        webView.LayoutParameters.Height = -1;

        base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
```

What's special about -2? Why did changing the Layout Parameter suddenly force the HTML to render as expected?

Answer (score 0):

in iOS you need to set HeightRequest initially. to something small. So that the scroll view would be created.

webview.HeightRequest = 20;

// code here